# How to output in console or json a data structured with correct column and row values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this table:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="saveTable">Save table</button>

<table id="table-data" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary removeColumn btn-block">Delete column</button>
      <br>
      <input class="form-control column_data" type="text" autofocus="" placeholder="Title" name="Name" value="Titolo">
    </th>
    <th>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary removeColumn btn-block">Delete column</button>
      <br>
      <input class="form-control column_data" type="text" autofocus="" placeholder="Title" name="Name">
    </th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="tr_clone">
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary removeRow">Delete row</button></td>
      <td><input class="form-control row_data" type="text" autofocus="" placeholder="data" name="who" value="22"></td>
      <td><input type="text" placeholder="data" name="datepicker_end" class="form-control row_data"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

When I click the `save button`, I would like to output either in console.log or ideally as a jSon. The issue I am facing is that columns and rows do not follow the correct index:

```
$('#saveTable').on("click", function() {
 $(".column_data").each(function(){
  var dataValue = $(this).val();
  console.log(dataValue + "\n");
   $(".row_data").each(function(){
    var dataValue = $(this).val();
    console.log(dataValue + "\n");
   });
 });
});
```

[JsFiddle playground](http://jsfiddle.net/Crw2C/1416/)

Comment: Your algorithm is wrong . The current implementation would just list ALL of the row's data N times, where N is the number of columns you have. I assume you want to print first the Column data (heading) and then only the rows but for that column?

Comment: @N.Ivanov exactly, that's what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: From the top of my head you would want to play with the index of the `<td>` element of each `<tr>`, so you would have to change your algorithm (where the second loop begins), to rather go over each `<tr>`, but take only the appropriate `<td>`, depending on the current column. Hope this helps!

Comment: @N.Ivanov an answer with some code would be of much more help tbh...

Comment: I have added an answer, which I believe solves your problem. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had some free time to take a look and try to implement what I mentioned in the comments.

It was a bit tricky to implement, as you don't directly access the table's rows and columns, and especially the way you wanted to group rows and columns, but with some algorithm magic, and the power of maths I managed to get it working.

Here is a working example where I print both row,column data, and I also build a custom object as you were trying where the `column_data` are the keys and `row_data` are the values in a list depending how many rows per column there are.

```js
$('#saveTable').on("click", function() {
  var colCounter = $(".column_data").length;
  var rowCounter = $(".row_data").length;

  var customObject = {};

  for (var i = 0; i < colCounter; i++) {
    console.log("Col-data: " + $(".column_data").eq(i).val());
    customObject[$(".column_data").eq(i).val()] = [];
    for (var j = 0 + i; j < rowCounter; j += colCounter) {
      console.log("Row-data: " + $(".row_data").eq(j).val());
      customObject[$(".column_data").eq(i).val()].push($(".row_data").eq(j).val());
    }
  }
  console.log(customObject);
});

$('#table-data input').on("change", function() {
  $(this).attr("value", $(this).attr("value"));
});

$(".table-striped tbody tr th input").each(function() {
  $(this).addClass("column_data");
});

$("#addTr").on('click', function() {
  var $tr = $('tbody tr.tr_clone');
  var $clone = $tr.clone();
  $clone.find(':text').val('');
  $tr.after($clone);
  $(".table-striped tbody tr td input").each(function() {
    $(this).addClass("row_data");
  });
});

$("#addTd").on("click", function() {
  $(".table-striped thead tr").append('<th><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary removeColumn btn-block">Delete column</button><br><input class="form-control" type="text" autofocus placeholder="Title" name="Name"></th>');
  $(".table-striped tbody tr").append('</td> <td><input type="text" placeholder="data" name="datepicker_end" class="form-control"></td>');
  $(document).find("thead th input").each(function() {
    $(this).addClass("column_data");
  });
  $(".table-striped tbody tr td input").each(function() {
    $(this).addClass("row_data");
  });
});

$(document).on("click", ".removeRow", function() {
  $(this).parent().parent()
  $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});

$(document).on("click", ".removeColumn", function() {
  var index = $(this).parent().index() + 1;
  $(this).closest("table").find("td:nth-child(" + index + ")").remove();
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">


  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <hr>
      <h3>Insert your data</h3>
      <button id="addTd" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
        Add Column
      </button>
      <button id="addTr" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
        Add Row
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="saveTable">Save table</button>
      <hr>
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="table-data" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th></th>
              <th>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary removeColumn btn-block">Delete column</button>
                <br>
                <input class="form-control column_data" type="text" autofocus placeholder="Title" name="Name" value="">
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr class="tr_clone">
              <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary removeRow">Delete row</button></td>
              <td><input class="form-control row_data" type="text" autofocus placeholder="data" name="who" value=""></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: thanks a lot, got there yesterday, now what I was about to do was to implement a clone of the table, in order to create a new one https://jsfiddle.net/fbh0o67o/179/